# JSON data format when attaching to variable

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get data back from a PHP call in JSON format which I already have setup. When I echo the JSON data is comes back in a right format

I am trying to process the data and send them into input fields. If I manually add the JSON data to my jQuery script it works fine, but if I try and call the returning data from the AJAX call it does not work, even though the data is structured the same either way.

This is what works

```
success: function(data) {
    var myobj = {"title":"botskonet"}

    for( k in myobj ){
        alert(myobj[k]);
        document.getElementById(k).value = myobj[k];
    }
}
```

but if I use this it does not work

```
success: function(data) {
    var myobj = data <--which if I echo it looks like this {"title":"botskonet"}

    for( k in myobj ){
        alert(myobj[k]);
        document.getElementById(k).value = myobj[k];
    }
}
```

and if I echo the JSON call from the data return, it is this which is identical to the manual one.

```
{"title":"botskonet"}
```

So I am not sure what the difference is between manually writing the JSON call as apposed to calling it back from an AJAX can and why its not working.

Comment: please try `JSON.parse(data)`. Also please post how your PHP is serializing the JSOn data to return back to the client.

Comment: that did it, thanks I change my code to this `var myobj = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Posted answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: @CesarBielich if the answer helped you, you should accept LimH's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are returning from PHP is a string in JSON format, so you need to parse it client side with `JSON.parse(data);` to turn it into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have not posted the whole code, I am assuming you are using one of the available methods in Jquery to make the AJAX request. You can specify a `dataType` parameter in such methods which is basically used to declare the type of data you are expecting from the server.

Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: <your-request-url>,
  data: <your-data>,
  success: function(){ ... },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

More details here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/